# Read command line arguments from a file

Tags: command-line, files

Directory structure:

```
/home
---ubuntu
------projects
---------project1
---------project2
---------project3
------.ignore
```

.ignore:

```
*project1* *project2*
```

If I run:

```
zip -r zipush.zip projects -x "$(< .ignore)"
```

Then it creates a zip containting all three projects - which is a wrong result. I want it to ignore project1 and project2.

However, it does work well when I write the arguments explicitly:

```
zip -r zipush.zip projects -x *project1* *project2*
```

But I don't understand why, because "$(< .ignore)" seems to work well when I type for example:

```
echo "$(< .ignore)"
```

Output:

```
 *project1* *project2*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change your .ignore file to this:

```
project1/*
project2/*
```

Second, change your `-x` switch to `-x@.ignore`.

Comment: Still not working. It's zipping all projects. I ran: zip -r zipush.zip projects -x@.ignore

Comment: I think it's the location of the .ignore file. Try `-x@projects/.ignore` or move it to `/home/ubuntu`.

Comment: OK I've solved that. I changed it to *project1* and *project2* (in different lines and it's working now.

Comment: with astersisks, SO for some reason uses asterisks in comment to make the font italic